# jQuery returning wrong width() for submit button

Tags: jquery

I have this simple example:

```
<input style="width:100px;" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit form"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert($('#submit').width());
    });
</script>
```

The alert says "84" using Chrome and "97" using IE 10
Why doesn't jQuery return "100"?

I'm using jQuery v1.10.2. I tried jQuery 1.6.4 and it returns the same wrong values.

Even

```
alert($('#submit').css('width'));
```

returns "84px"

Comment: This is a guess but is it something to do with the parent element? If you check in the console in FF or Chrome you can see other elements that might be causing the issue, font size, padding, margins etc.

Comment: `alert($('#submit').css('width'));` returns 100px on firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/wKkSH/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth) instead:

```
$("#submit").outerWidth();
```

From the linked page:

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements, including padding and border

Comment: Works perfect even in old IE :) Thank you!